# Javascript filter data that does not exists from a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I have my code below . The value is an array of objects. Then i get a filte from each object which is the VIN. And then i use the vin data which is the filter to filter data from the database. Now i want to know how could i seperate those data that does not exist in the database from the value object. Seperat those data from the value object which are not found from the query result. Thanks.

## Code

```
>   complete: function (results, content) {
> 
>               var results = _.each(results, function (value, key) {
>                   for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
> 
>                       var itemToUpdate = {
>                           VIN: value[i].VIN
>                       }
> 
>                       Vehicle.model.findOne(itemToUpdate, function (error, vehicleObject) {
> 
> 
>                           if (vehicleObject) {
> 
>                               console.log("vehicleObject VIN" , vehicleObject.VIN)
>   
> 
>                           }
> 
>                           
> 
>                       })
> 
>                       
> 
>                   }
> 
>               })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
complete: async (results, content) {
    let notInDbValue = [];
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
            var itemToUpdate = {
                VIN: results[i][j].VIN
            }
            let vehicleObject = await Vehicle.model.findOne(itemToUpdate);
            if (vehicleObject) {
                console.log("vehicleObject VIN", vehicleObject.VIN);
            } else {
                notInDbValue.push(results[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is that when i access notInDbValue outside the loop , the array is empty ?

Comment: Due to async function data in not available outside the mongoose function. I have updated the answer please check

Comment: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Make your function async

Comment: I did follow your answer

Comment: @Rahulkumar the each function callback should be async i.e. `_.each(results, async (value, key) => { .. }` and I don't think you need another for loop inside the `each` iterator since it's already a loop

Comment: can you provide an answer @chridam

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: @same rahul , array is still empty outside

Comment: @rajiv use normal loop

Comment: At this part var results = _.each(results, function (value, key) {